# Who plays MacGyver in the Stargate universe?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the first episode of *Stargate: SG-1*, it is implied that MacGyver is a TV show in the *Stargate* universe, when Samantha Carter comments on the compactness of the DHD, and how it "took them years to **MacGyver** a system [emphasis mine]" on Earth.

If this is the case, what actor is likely to be portraying MacGyver, as Richard Dean Anderson probably doesn't exist?

(Caveat 1: This answer probably does not have a canonical answer.)

(Caveat 2: The canonicity of the existence of the MacGyver TV show in-universe is possibly dubious, as the recut of the first episode, "Children of the Gods", omits the line entirely, and no further (spoken) references are made to the show.)

(Caveat 3: It is of course possible that Richard Dean Anderson *does* exist in the *Stargate* 'verse, in a Rainier Wolfcastle type situation.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for the Movies & TV stack?

Comment: @Monty129: I feel it's the kind of troubling philosophical question science fiction is wont to raise, maybe?

Comment: Why wouldn't Richard Dean Anderson exist in the Stargate universe?

Comment: as you point out, this question doesn't and likely never will have a canon answer, so any answers to it would be speculation and baseless guessing...

Comment: TV Tropes reference: [Celebrity Paradox](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CelebrityParadox). They've got a section on SG-1.

Comment: Don't forget the [blooper from the "ice planet" episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRkexJ-MBCQ)!

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield As discussed [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184) and [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/957/5184), "there is no canon answer" is sometimes the most valid answer.

Comment: @phantom42 true, but the asker already knows that, by their own admission, and is clearly asking for something more. I don't think there is any such possible answer; however, based on those meta questions, I'll VTR.

Comment: There was also the line where he and Carter were trapped in a room and he said something to the effect of "You know I could get us out of here if I just had a rubber band and a paper clip"

Comment: I feel it's worth re-iterating @SystemDown's point. Richard Dean Anderson is not playing himself. Why wouldn't Richard exist as an actor in this universe? Why would MacGyver not be a show in this universe? That's why this is such a fun question.

Comment: I've nominated for re-opening. The name MacGyver is mentioned in the show and in the scripts. I'm sure there must be an interview or FAQ that covers this, allowing a canon answer.

Comment: This question seems similar (not identical, but similar) to asking "Who would go on to star in 'Big' in the 'Apollo 13' universe, since Tom Hanks probably wouldn't exist?"

Answer (score 16):

This question is fun and it really was just improvised on the set as a joke. Look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PdY3L-JYzk). They were just having fun by breaking down the "fourth wall." There is no canon, as far as I know. It's just a wink to the fans and a laugh for the people making the show.

I only post this as an answer instead of a comment because of the bloopers and lack of canon evidence. I don't think it is "merely guessing" that referencing an actor's previous role is a joke for fans. It seems to me there can be no other answer especially when you see the clip above poking fun at Richard.

Comment: It should also be noted that in the remastered "Children of the Gods: The Final Cut", they changed the line from "MacGyver" to "jury rig." So retroactively this situation didn't happen and there is no paradox. Then again, SGA 2x05 "Condemned" had McKay asking "What am I, MacGyver?"